# Options for dynamically adding reducers within a package being consumed

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have 2 node packages A and B with A consuming B. I have the store being defined using `createStore` and `combineReducers` in A. This just has the reducers in A.

I want to add a new reducer in package B. What are my options to connect it to the store? I've been looking at `redux-injector`. The other thing I am thinking of is to move reducer from package B to A but that would mean that B would have to consume A and will create a cycle.

Are there any better ways of handling this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your requirement

```
    A-->
     store.jsx

    B-->
     reducer1.js
     reducer2.js
```

So in `store.jsx` you will `import` reducers from package B
as

```
import reducer1 from "../B/reducer1";
import reducer2 from "../B/reducer2";
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  reducer1,
 reducer12,
});
export const configureStore = (initialState) => {
 //your other store configuration
};
```

If you want to add any more reducer in package B simply import and add it to `store.jsx` file.
Where `store.jsx` is your store configuration.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear, I've updated my question. Package A has a reducer which is being used to create the store. Now, I want to introduce a new reducer in package B.

Comment: It will not matter in which package you want to introduce your reducer.just import added reducer with correct path in your store config.

Comment: I'm using react with redux and I am initializing/creating store in a Component containing the `Provider` to wrap other containers/components. If I use `store.jsx` do I just import the `store` and use it? Is there any documentation/examples around using `store.jsx`?

Comment: @linuxNoob The redux site has examples of application structure, e.g. https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples  You don't have to use a dedicated `store.js` file, but then your main index file should be doing that setup then and importing all reducers and the parent component then (and nothing much else).  You can see the pattern used in most examples on the redux site pretty clearly.  What you shouldn't be doing is creating the store and having application logic / rendering in the same file / component.